# Testing Field Injection VS Constructor Injection

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, mockito

I try to replace field injection by constuctor injection in my controller because it seems to be a best practice.
When I run the application, it works with both solution.

My issue is with the unit testing of my Controller.
I write the test class for the Controller where I use field injection.
It works fine.
Now I replace field injection by constuctor injection. The test fail.

Here is my initial Controller (with field injection) :

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        MyPojo myPojo = myService.getMyPojo();
        model.addAttribute("myPojo", myPojo);
        return "dashboard";
    }

}
```

Now the new Controller (with constuctor injection) :

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    private final MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    public DashboardController(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        MyPojo myPojo = myService.getMyPojo();
        model.addAttribute("myPojo", myPojo);
        return "dashboard";
    }

}
```

And the test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyApplication.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:/application.properties")
public class DashboardControllerUnitTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private DashboardController dashboardController;

    @Mock
    private MyService myService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(dashboardController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getDashboard() throws Exception {
        doReturn(new MyPojo()).when(myService).getMyPojo();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(model().attribute("myPojo", equalTo(new MyPojo()))); // The test fail here
        verify(myService).getMyPojo();
    }

}
```

If I run the test with the initial version of my Controller, it works fine.
But if I run the same test with the new version of the Controller (with constructor injection), myPojo is null and the test fail.

It seems like mockito doesn't mock the service if it is constructor injected.
Do you have any idea why I have the issue and how to solve it ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `@MockBean` annotation on `MyService` instead?  And use a simple `@Autowired` on `DashboardController`? And remove the whole `setup()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change setup method to something like this:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    dashboardController = new DashboardController(myService);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(dashboardController)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works. I didn't think to initialize the controller.